# How can I restore data from an iPhone backup without a physical iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

I recently lost my iPhone. I know that I have done full backups with iTunes (now Music.app?). I don't have a physical iPhone and I am not interested in getting one right now. How do I restore data from those backups?

Comment: Something like iMazing, which allows you to open backups on disk.

Comment: You've asked this question seven months ago. What have you tried in the meantime to access your data (including the tool recommended in the comment above)?